# Is there a way to track a run away process?

Tags: software-recommendation, logging, memory-usage

Recently I've been getting a rather annoying problem, which seems to be linked to Firefox-Trunk, Thunderbird-Trunk, or possible Compiz (default 12.04 `compiz` with Unity). At random (it seems) the system becomes unusable because the RAM is suddenly full.

I thought it was a Firefox only problem (with Google+ - if you scroll it was doing this), but further investigation revealed other potential causes. I've since disabled all addons and the problem has not yet occured (at the time of writing) - but I'm waiting to see - because I had to start KDM just to log in (Lightdm freezes now thanks to having to kill the xserver twice).

Preramble aside - is there a way that I can track what process is going out of hand (maybe by a log?) so I can fix it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Preramble aside - is there a way that I can track what process is going out of hand (maybe by a log?) so I can fix it later?

If you suspect it's a specific process, just start it from within a bash script, calling `ulimit -v N` first, where N is the max virtual memory *in kilobytes* you want to give it before the kernel kills it. You'll know what it is when it dies ;)

You could also try setting a simple cron job which appends the output of `ps` with specific parameters (for memory) to a log every minute and parse later.

Finally, try *monit* (in repos), which monitors processes and can take actions such as killing, restarting, etc. when specific thresholds are exceeded.

Comment: P.S. Can you write an example of how to correctly use ulimit to launch the process with a limit? Also an example of how to use monit would be nice :)

Comment: Will do in the next 2-3 days. Please feel free to remind with a comment (they can be deleted later) if I have forgotten! :)